# Install Ubuntu on Second Internal Drive fully separate from Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

Let's say I have Drive C:, and Drive D:.

Drive C: has Windows 7 on it, and Drive D: is currently completely empty.

I would like to install Ubuntu on Drive D: without adding a bootloader/GRUB to the regular startup of my computer. So If i restart it, or turn it on, it just normally boots to Windows 7, and once in Windows 7, it can't even access or detect Drive D:

But if I enter BIOS or advanced startup during a boot, and choose to boot from Drive D:, then I boot into Ubuntu.

Is this possible? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

My motherboard (Abit IC7-G) bios is set up to allow me to select booting from 1GB usb (which is where I have grub2 for ubuntu 12.0.4 Alternate install CD because of my raid). After booting into grub2 I can hold down shift or use up down key to select which os to startup. Removing the USB can keep most people out of my linux system and the bios automatically selects "boot from other device" when the usb is removed.

If the usb is installed at pc bootup motherboard bios recognizes it and bios allows me to alternately select "boot from other device" instead of boot from usb which is set to raid drive and contains most of my hard drive space (raid spanning which is in other bios settings). This setting boots directly to xp (no grub involved).

The answer may be that it depends upon your bios.
One other thing that I did was to install xp first.
Which makes grub act independently.
If your grub is to be installed on your "D" so that you can dual boot you may be able to set your bios to boot to "D"
For this to work, you may also need to remove the physical wiring connections from your "C" and then install ubuntu to "D".
However, removing "C" means that grub will not ,without some editing, recognize the "C" operating system.
And most likely windows won't be able to see linux, however, when running linux you can see and even edit windows stuff and partitions, etc. Also be careful.
Be sure to completely power off to make any wiring changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well with all due respect I'll have to say that although the first part of **user2654514**'s answer sounds right, as well as a pretty cool way to set up a machine, The part about installing **Ubuntu** on a drive that is temporarily isolated, will (although perhaps necessary) not lead to a need to edit the **grub boot-loader**.

> Once you finish the install(s), boot and press ***F12*** to enter your ***boot-device menu***.
>
> ```
>  (Same on most machines, however your boot-menu key may be 
> different).
> ```
>
> > Then boot from the drive containing the **grub boot-loader** & **Ubuntu**.
> >
> > ```
> > (Once you've started Ubuntu it may update grub automatically but the way I
> >  know it works (for me) is to;
> > ```
> >
> > Then start **Nautilus** and mount the drive containing the **Windows** installation.
> >  Then you may *exit* and *Restart*. 
> > When the computer boots
> >
> > ```
> >  (I forgot to mention set your grub / Ubuntu drive to the boot-1st drive)
> > ```
> >
> > Hold down **LEFT-SHIFT**
> >
> > ```
> > (my machine the OS Selection screen shows always by default{not sure why})
> > ```
> >
> > to get the ***OS Selection menu*** and Viola! both/all of your *OS's* should be there...
> >
> > ```
> >  Hope this helps : /   -Bill
> > ```